# Is matplotlib broken?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

When I simply try :

```py
import matplotlib as plt
```

I immediately get this error :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Graph test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot
  File "C:\Users\Elève\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from . import cbook, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\Elève\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 28, in <module>
    from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
  File "C:\Users\Elève\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\fontconfig_pattern.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pyparsing import (Literal, ZeroOrMore, Optional, Regex, StringEnd,
  File "C:\Users\Elève\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 5660, in <module>
    _reBracketExpr = Literal("[") + Optional("^").setResultsName("negate") + Group(OneOrMore(_charRange | _singleChar)).setResultsName("body") + "]"
  File "C:\Users\Elève\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 1482, in setResultsName
    return self._setResultsName(name, listAllMatches)
  File "C:\Users\Elève\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 1485, in _setResultsName
    newself = self.copy()
  File "C:\Users\Elève\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 1439, in copy
    cpy = copy.copy(self)
AttributeError: module 'copy' has no attribute 'copy'
```

What's happening ? Am I the only one ? I already tried to uninstall and install it again, didn't work... How could I fix that ?

Comment: do you have a file `copy.py`?

Comment: Yes, I use it to copy paste code I'm not using... I shouldn't ? ^^'

Comment: rename that file to something different. It shadows the built-in module [copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)

Comment: Didn't think of that... That actually worked ! Thanks ^^'